# Data in not being sent to database

Tags: php, html

I'm learning to code web pages and I tumbled into a problem which don't know how to fix it. I think I did everything well, but it doesn't send data to the server. I bought an html template, and I'm working on it. When I modified the action in the form tag it didn't send data. This is my html form(full page [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nL4bmhsx/)):

```
<form action="includes/registerhandler.php" method="POST" role="form" id="form_register" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <!--<div class="form-register-success">
                <i class="entypo-check"></i>
                <h3>You have been successfully registered.</h3>
                <p>We have emailed you the confirmation link for your account.</p>
            </div>-->

            <div class="form-steps">

                <div class="step current" id="step-1">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon">
                                <i class="entypo-user"></i>
                            </div>

                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="FullName" id="name" placeholder="Full Name" autocomplete="off" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon">
                                <i class="entypo-phone"></i>
                            </div>

                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Phone" id="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" data-mask="phone" autocomplete="off" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon">
                                <i class="entypo-calendar"></i>
                            </div>

                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="B-D" id="birthdate" placeholder="Date of Birth (DD/MM/YYYY)" data-mask="date" autocomplete="off" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="button" data-step="step-2" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-login">
                            <i class="entypo-right-open-mini"></i>
                            Next Step
                        </button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        Step 1 of 2
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="step" id="step-2">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon">
                                <i class="entypo-user-add"></i>
                            </div>

                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="UserName" id="username" placeholder="Username" data-mask="[a-zA-Z0-1\.]+" data-is-regex="true" autocomplete="off" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon">
                                <i class="entypo-mail"></i>
                            </div>

                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Email" id="email" data-mask="email" placeholder="E-mail" autocomplete="off" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon">
                                <i class="entypo-lock"></i>
                            </div>

                            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="PassWord" id="password" placeholder="Choose Password" autocomplete="off" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-login">
                            <i class="entypo-right-open-mini"></i>
                            Complete Registration
                        </button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        Step 2 of 2
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </form>
```

And this is my PHP script:

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';

if(isset($_POST)){
    $FullName = $_POST['FullName'];
    $UserName = $_POST['UserName'];
    $B-D = $_POST['B-D'];
    $Gender = $_POST['Gender'];
    $Address = $_POST['Address'];
    $Phone = $_POST['Phone'];
    $Email = $_POST['Email'];
    $City = $_POST['City'];
    $Country = $_POST['Country'];
    $PassWord = $_POST['PassWord'];

        $repons = $bdd->query('select count(*) from user where Username =\'' .$UserName. '\'')->fetchColumn();

                        if($repons == 1){
                            echo 'user already exist';
                        }
                        else{
                                $req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO user VALUES ("",:UserName,:PassWord,:B-D,:Email,:FullName,:Phone,:Gender,:Address,:City,:Country)');
                                            $req->execute(  
                                                            array(  ':FullName' => $FullName,                                           ':UserName' => $UserName, ':B-D' => $BirthDate,                                     ':Gender' => $Gender, ':Phone' => $Phone, ':Email' => $Email, ':City' => $City, ':Country' => $Country, ':PassWord' => $PassWord, ':Address' => $Address));

                                                $idp = $bdd->lastInsertId();

                                echo 'you are now a member confirmation email sent';
                            }
else{
     echo 'submit is not set';
}



?>
```

I add a session variable to test if the file has been executed but it still didn't show a thing.

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific, let us know what you are expecting to happen and what is actually happening?

Comment: actually the php code hasn't been able to execute  at all, and I don't know why.

Comment: PHP variables are case sensitive. `$_session` and `$_SESSION` are completely different things.

Comment: Thanks, @DontVoteMeDown.

Comment: I just add your code and nothing has changed in my folder.

Comment: Most of your PHP code is commented out. Is it echoing anything? Do you get any errors?

Comment: i just changed it and still the same problem.

Comment: the problem is that the php file is not being executed at all

Comment: I copy-pasted your entire <form>, when I click the button "Complete Registration", the PHP code is invoked. Doesn't it happen to you?

Comment: no it doesn't happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP variables are case sensitive. And unless I'm mistaken the native PHP session variable is `$_SESSION`. So if that is your exact PHP code above and all you want it to do is increment the value of key 'var' then you need to use the `$_SESSION['var']`.

It would look more like this.

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['var']))
{
    $_SESSION['var']++;
}
else
{
    $_SESSION['var'] = 0;
}
```

And of course to test that the PHP script is increasing the key value properly then you need to output `$_SESSION['var']` or some other indication to the client side, or text file, etc.

You must have been editing your question as I was posting my answer. But I would change your last PHP line to:

```
echo $_SESSION['var'];

?>
```

Just so that your output is more relevant and helpful.

*I would leave this in a comment, however I don't have enough reputation points.*
Reading your further comments on your question it may be helpful to check if your PHP script is being run at all. I would check the network tab of Chrome's developer tools to see if you are finding the correct script and what errors are being returned.

Comment: i modified my question! i just add those SESSION variables to test if the file had been executed! so the Variable "var" doesn't exist even after the execution!

Comment: You are correct, you've changed your question to the point that it isn't the same question at all. So now my answer makes very little sense. If you had your first question/problem solved you should have accepted an answer [or added your own answer and accepted it] and asked a new question.